# Visual Bakery extra margins when adding pricing tables

Tags: html, css, wordpress, width, margin

On a page I've built using visual bakery. It is wider than 100% and making a horizontal scroll bar appear. I've looked using firebug and can't see whats pushing this extra space on the right.

I think it is something to do with the pricing tables built using visual bakery and when I put them display none the problem goes.

But I can't find what causing the problem to fix it.

http://www.pf2.co.uk/memberships/

Comment: at a first glance, the issue appears to be the animations of the slides.. It looks like they are sliding in from the sides where their starting value is off the page. if "overflow:hidden" is set for those sections, it should prevent the scrolling.

Comment: Thank you ! Fixed the problem, it was bugging me for ages. VERY much appreciated :)

Comment: not a problem - glad you fixed it